# a href... a:link, a:visited, interfered with <a href> image link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below style in my `<head></head>` to display my menu:

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #98bf21;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;   
}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

The problem now is, `a:link, a:visited` AND `a:hover, a:active`, is displaying a box menu on my `div` image link. Here is the code:

```
<div id="content1">
 <a href="inside_page.html">
 <img src="images/adeliepenguin_250x200.jpg" alt="Adenlie Penguin" height="200" width="250"></a> 
</div>
```

My question is: Is there a way I can stop it to display that menu box my image div space?

Here is the full code of the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Birds </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="birds2.css" />
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #98bf21;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;   
}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">Birds In Danger</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">Birds Habitants</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="flash"> Flash messaging area</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="content1">
     <a href="inside_page.html">
       <img src="images/adeliepenguin_250x200.jpg" alt="Adenlie Penguin" height="200" width="250">
     </a> 
    </div>
    <div id="content2"><img src="images/American_Goldfinch_250x200.jpg" alt="American Goldfinch" height="200" width="250"></div>
    <div id="content3"><img src="images/blue-jay-Glamour_250x200.jpg" alt="Blue Jay Glamour" height="200" width="250"></div>
    <div id="content4"><img src="images/american-robin-250x200.jpg" alt="Blue Jay Glamour" height="200" width="250"></div>
  </div>
   <div class="footer_menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">Birds In Danger</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">Birds Habitants</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"> Footer area</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you get a jsfiddle demonstrating this?  It's not entirely clear what the issue is.

Comment: no idea what `creates menu box` means. Use browser dev tools to inspect rules applying to each element and write more specific rules (or adjust exiting ones) to modify display

Comment: Making `<a>` tags `display:block` globally seems like a really bad idea in the first place

Comment: charlietfl, what do you suggest?

Comment: not sure what use case for them being block is but use a class to do that. Same with width , background etc. Doing that at tag level means you will fight it every time you need to use an `<a>` for something that those styles weren't planned for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your looking for?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
.menu a:link,
a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  font-weight: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #98bf21;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Just prefix the CSS for your anchor tags with the `.menu` class so it only targets your menu.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/3vdh2dxL/1/

Also, I have changed your footer menu to use the same `.menu` class.

Comment: Andrew Ashton, thank you very much! Your solution worked fine after updating my code with your proposed solution. It is only targeting class .menu rather than <a href></a>, as I have it before. I spent over 3 hours working on this. Again, Thank you so much. God bless you! Be blessed Andrew! I have learned from this.